# Which Phoenix version should I use with HBase in Cloudera 5.5 and Hortonworks 2.4?

Tags: apache, hbase, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-phoenix

Is there a single version of phoenix that is compatible with HBase provided in both Cloudera 5.5 and Hortonworks 2.4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hortonworks provides custom fixes and "backports" to their version of Phoenix in their HDP distribution. Cloudera may do the same as well.

I am assuming that you are asking about a client version that is compatible with both server versions.

Are you using the "thin" client jars? Do you find that your application does not work for one distribution or the other (dependent on which version jars you have)? Your application may work for both distributions if you use the non-thin jars.

If you would like to continue using the thin client, you may have to set `phoenix.queryserver.serialization` to `JSON`. HDP 2.3.4+ use `PROTOBUF` by default whereas CDH does not currently support `PROTOBUF`.

---

---

---

---

If you are asking about manually installing a version of the Phoenix server that can be installed on both distributions, both use HBase 1.1.x. Any Phoenix version 4.4+ can be used on either distribution. But I recommend using the version that is distributed with the platform.

Answer (score 2):

A Phoenix 4.5.2 package for CDH 5.5.x is available via Cloudera Labs:

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/11/new-apache-phoenix-4-5-2-package-from-cloudera-labs/

Note however that Cloudera Labs packages are for dev/test only (not supported by Cloudera).